# Powershell - Calling Stored Procedure - Works with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection but not with System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection

Tags: sql, t-sql, powershell

I have a strange problem. I have a powershell script that I've been trying to get to work with an ODBC connection after having been designed to work with a direct SQLConnection.

When $odbc is false, this code runs fine, when it is $true I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Procedure or function 'External_DeficiencyListAll' expects parameter '@startTime', which was not supplied." At C:\Users\afreeberg\Documents\Hyland\Trinitas\Deficiency Polling Powershell\Deficiency_Polling.ps1:317 char:19 +     $dataAdapter.Fill <<<< ($results[0]) | Out-Null     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Here is the code:

```
if ($odbc)
{
    LogWrite("Using ODBC Connection")
    $odbcConnection = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $odbcConnection.ConnectionString = $odbcString
    $odbcCommand = $odbcConnection.CreateCommand()
    $odbcCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $odbcCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[External_DeficiencyListAll]"
    $odbcCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", $startTime) | Out-Null
    $outParameter = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter
    $outParameter.ParameterName = "@nowTime"
    $outParameter.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
    $outParameter.DbType = [System.Data.DbType]::DateTime
    $odbcCommand.Parameters.Add($outParameter) | Out-Null
    $dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.ODBC.OdbcDataAdapter $odbcCommand

}
else
{
    LogWrite ("Using SQL Connection")
    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.sqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connString
    $sqlCommand = $sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
    $sqlCommand.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
    $sqlCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[External_DeficiencyListAll]"
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startTime", $startTime) | Out-Null
    $outParameter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter
    $outParameter.ParameterName = "@nowTime"
    $outParameter.Direction = [System.Data.ParameterDirection]::Output
    $outParameter.DbType = [System.Data.DbType]::DateTime
    $sqlCommand.Parameters.Add($outParameter) | Out-Null
    $dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $sqlCommand
}

LogWrite ("Querying for deficiencies updated since: " + $startTime)
#Initialize Dataset object to hold results from stored procedure query
$results = @()
$results += @(New-Object System.Data.Dataset)


#Execute query using $dataAdapter and filling $results
$dataAdapter.Fill($results[0]) | Out-Null

$results += @($sqlCommand.Parameters["@nowTime"].Value)

#return $results
$results
```

Important parameters:

```
$odbcString = "DSN=defPolLTest" Corresponds to an ODBC connection set up to point to the SQL database referred to in $connString

$connString = 'Server=ONE-017125\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DeficiencyPolling;User Id=dpolling;Password=password;'

$startTime corresponds to the last run time of the script, stored in the registry. Is a DateTime value.
```

So in the case of using a SQLConnection, the parameter is recognized, but it does not when using an OdbcConnection...

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using this method instead of something simpler, like [`Invoke-SQLCommad`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx)?

Comment: Agreed with @MikeFal , also check if your odbc connections are set up properly on the machine you're running from.  C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe